# How do I randomly rotate a square in a 2D array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib

My task to detect a rectangle no matter where it is in a picture. For that, I generated random pixels and randomly generated squares in the picture. It varies in shape and size.

The only thing that is missing is that the rectangle is always at a straight angle. **I want the rectangle to be randomly rotated.**

**What I have now:**

[image]

**What I want:**

[image]

My code for the first (straight) plot:

```py
plt.figure(figsize=(4, 4))
s = 100                                             # Plot size (100, 100)
min = 10                                            # Minimum rectangle height
max = 20                                            # Maximum rectangle height

background = np.random.randint(0, 256, (s, s, 3))   # Random background pixels

a = np.random.randint(min, max)                     # Little side of rectangle
b = np.random.randint(a*1.5, a*2.5)                 # Big side of rectangle

xx, yy = np.where(np.ones((a, b)) == 1)             # Initial coordinates of the rectangle

cx = np.random.randint(0 + a, s - a)                # Random horizontal location
cy = np.random.randint(0 + a, s - b)                # Random vertical location

background[xx + cx, yy + cy] = np.random.randint(200, 255, background[xx + cx, yy + cy].shape)

plt.imshow(background)
plt.xlim(0, s)
plt.ylim(0, s)
plt.title('Random Square')
plt.show()
```

Comment: You haven't asked a question.

Answer (score 1):

Since your picture is filled with random pixels, I'd recommend to draw the rectangle in the middle of the picture, then rotate it (use OpenCV for that, particularly `cv2.getRotationMatrix2D()` and `cv2.warpAffine()`), then translate (offset) in some direction so the position is also becomes random.

Once done with rotation and translation, you may clip the picture to your size -- because of rotations you may want to start with a picture approximately two times bigger than the result you want to get.

If you need more help with rotation, here's a link with a tutorial: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/01/02/rotate-images-correctly-with-opencv-and-python/

Comment: *"because of rotations you may want to start with a picture approximately two times bigger than the result you want to get"* what do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Your shape is simple, but I like to use *[einsum](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html)* for shapes with hundreds of points.

You can get the idea from this. `s00` is just a polygon represented by an ndarray:

```
array([[ 1.5,  1.5],
       [ 0.0,  10.0],
       [ 10.0,  10.0],
       [ 10.0,  0.0],
       [ 1.5,  1.5]])

angle = 22.5
angle = np.radians(angle)
c, s = np.cos(angle), np.sin(angle)
R = np.array(((c, s), (-s, c)))
cent = np.mean(s00, axis=0)
new_cent = [10., 10.]
ch = np.einsum('ij,jk->ik', s00 - cent, R) + new_cent
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I did a few adjustments. They are commented in the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import matplotlib as mpl

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4, 4))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

s = 100                                             # Plot size (100, 100)
min = 10                                            # Min rectangle height
max = 20                                            # Max rectangle height

degree = np.random.randint(0, 360)                  # Random rectangle rotation
background = np.random.randint(0, 256, (s, s, 3))   # Random background pixels

a = np.random.randint(min, max)                     # Little side of rectangle
b = np.random.randint(a*1.5, a*2.5)                 # Big side of rectangle

cx = np.random.randint(0 + a, s - a)                # Random horizontal location
cy = np.random.randint(0 + a, s - b)                # Random vertical location

pt = patches.Rectangle((cx,cy), a, b, color="white",  alpha=0.7)   # Rectangle with random sides and location
rt = mpl.transforms.Affine2D().rotate_deg_around(cx+a/2, cy+b/2, degree) + ax.transData # Set random rotation
pt.set_transform(rt)                                                 # Use random rotation to rotate rectangle
ax.add_patch(pt)                                                     # Add rectangle to plot


background[0, 0] = np.random.randint(200, 255, background[0, 0].shape)

plt.imshow(background)
plt.xlim(0, s)
plt.ylim(0, s)
plt.title('Random Square')
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image: Output image]